# How to Click on checkboxes one by one in Groovy/Geb?

Tags: html, css, groovy, automation, geb

I was working on an automation script using Groovy/Geb and the HTML code looks like the tags below:

```
<table class="backgrid">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="select-all-header-cell">
            <input tabindex="-1" type="checkbox">
        </th>
        <th>
            <a>
                List Item<b class="sort-caret"></b>
            </a>
        </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="select-row-cell">
                <input tabindex="-1" type="checkbox">
            </td><td class="string-cell">CAD</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="select-row-cell">
                <input tabindex="-1" type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td class="string-cell">
                USD
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="select-row-cell">
                <input tabindex="-1" type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td class="string-cell">.
                GBP
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="select-row-cell">
                <input tabindex="-1" type="checkbox">
            </td>
            <td class="string-cell">
                KPW
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I need to click on the checkboxes inside the   one by one and then move to the next stage of the automation. But I am stuck here. I know for clicking checkboxes I should work with interact {} but I can't find any sample example for this kind of stuff. Any kind of hints or suggestions would be a great help for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use `interact {}` to achieve it - there is a much easier way using `click()`.

To click the checkbox in header you can use:

```
$("table.backgrid thead input").click()
```

To click on the currency checkboxes use:

```
def checkboxes = $("table.backgrid tbody input")
checkboxes[0].click() //CAD
checkboxes[2].click() //GBP
```

Comment: Exactly! I was badly looking for this. Thanks a ton, @erdi.

Answer (score 0):

[Quoting the docs](http://www.gebish.org/manual/current/all.html#accessing_input_values)

> [...] Calling value(value) will set the current value of all elements in the Navigator. The argument can be of any type and will be coerced to a String if necessary. The exceptions are that when setting a checkbox value the method expects a boolean...

So, I didn't try this myself, but I think that if you can change your html to something like this (note that I added a **name** attribute to the  element)

```
[...]
    <td class="select-row-cell">
        <input tabindex="-1" type="checkbox" name="GBP">
    </td>
    <td class="string-cell">.
        GBP
    </td>
[...]
```

Then the next code should do the trick:

```
$("checkbox", name: "GBP").value(true)    //Should set the checkbox to 'checked'
```

Comment: I can't change the HTML as it's fixed by the UI Lead :S I didn't find any option with the existing HTML!